# Crop image overflow to edge of browser window

Tags: overflow, background-image

I'm currently developing a responsive website and have a certain image within a set amount of 'columns' (div size) for the site. This image is bigger than the size of div itself so flows over the edges (using html  and not CSS Background-Image). When I use the CSS background-image method the image gets cut off to fit the div and overflow:visible doesn't fix it (from what I've read you can't have a background-image overflow it's own div).

So I want this image to overflow it's div but also have the image be cropped to the edge of the browser window, otherwise I have a big empty white bar down the side of the website when you resize the browser window for smaller screen devices, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XypX.jpg

Are there any known methods of solving this or does Javascript need to be used to fix it (I know little JavaScript so I couldn't figure it out myself). Thanks in advance.

edit: Still no luck, been searching everywhere. Would love any help, thanks guys.

edit 2: Figured it out! Was a very simple fix of adding overflow:hidden to my hero unit (big containing div). I feel so stupid it took me so long to figure out such a simple fix.

Comment: can you post your current HTML markup & CSS? also it wasn't clear to me if you need to use background-image or if that was just something you tried in order to fix your issue

Comment: I tried both background-image and just using and <img> tag (the img tag method allows the overflow though). The markup was like this but I tried a bunch of different methods: <div class="five columns standingPig"><img src="images/standingPig.png" class="standingPig"></div>. There's an adjacent div to the left which takes up the remaining columns. The CSS is just currently: img.standingPig {
 position: relative;
 top: 6px;
 display: inline-block;
}. I currently have no preferred method, just anything that works!